# Fetching data from MySQL table, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$get="SELECT dial_prod_total FROM dial_product WHERE dial_prod_id='$dpname'";
$idgen=mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());
$total=$idgen+$dpqty;
$dpbuy="UPDATE dial_product set dial_prod_total= '$total'".
       "WHERE dial_prod_id='$dpname'";
$result1=mysql_query($dpbuy) or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to get the data in the column `dial_prod_total` using the ID stored in `$dpname` and then update the value and store in the same column. The value is replaced in the column but it's not the correct value. What is the mistake I have made? Please help me.

Comment: $idgen isn't the value of the query...it's like a result object. You have to get the actual number with mysql_fetch_row or something

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: thank u  friends....  i will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do

```
UPDATE dial_product SET dial_prod_total = dial_prod_total + $dpqty
WHERE dial_prod_id = '$dpname'
```

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: it shows error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dial_prod_id = 'prod6'' at line 1"

Comment: @praveenrsmart `dpqty` is apparently an empty string

Comment: no its not. bec i am using it in two places.. when inserting into the first table i am getting the value, while updating alone i am getting problem

Comment: @praveenrsmart can you print out the whole query before you run it and show it to me?

Comment: $dpbuy="INSERT INTO dail_prod_buy(dial_prod_id,dial_dob,dail_prod_arrived,dial_buy_bill,dial_buy_cost)".
"VALUES('$dpname','$dpdor','$dpcost','$dpqty','$dpdetail')";
$result=mysql_query($dpbuy) 
or die(mysql_error());

Comment: if($dpqty){
  $get="SELECT dial_prod_total FROM dial_product WHERE dial_prod_id='$dpname'";
  $idgen=mysql_query($get)
  or die(mysql_error());
 }
 echo $idgen;
 if($idgen){
  $total=$idgen+$dpqty;
  $dpbuy1="UPDATE dial_product set dial_prod_total = dial_prod_total + ".$dpqty." WHERE dial_prod_id = ".$dpname." ";
  $result1=mysql_query($dpbuy1) 
  or die(mysql_error());
 }

Comment: first comment followed by second one. bec it shows.. too long so i split and sent

Comment: it worked sorry i had some few mistakes like putting quoutes.. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You query can be rebuild as below.

```
"UPDATE dial_product set dial_prod_total = dial_prod_total + ".$total." WHERE dial_prod_id = ".$dpname." ";
```